# Capture keypress from Minecraft Pi in Python

Tags: python, minecraft

I've been playing around with the Minecraft Python API and I'd like to run some of my code in response to a keypress within the game. I'm able to selectively run code based on player position or block hit events, but I'd like to bind code to a particular keypress.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to capture a keypress from a regular (USB)keyboard and you are asking how to code this in python. I cannot see where it is specific to Raspberry Pi. Where is the problem with the RasPi?

Answer (score 1):

You could try importing `keyboard` and using code a bit like this:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('e'):
            print('E hotkey pressed')
            break
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break
```

Bear in mind that you have to install `keyboard` using `pip3 install keyboard`.

This module requires administrative privileges and thus must run under `sudo python3`